# How to store an Enumeration within a MongoCaseClassField in Lift Record?

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

Using Lift Record, when I try to retrieve the MongoDB entry below, a `NullPointerException` is raised when the `.asHtml` method of `MongoCaseClassField` is called.

```
object MyEnumeration extends Enumeration {
  val A, B, C = Value
}

case class MyCaseClass(en: MyEnumeration.Value) 

class MyRecord extends MongoRecord[MyRecord] with MongoId[MyRecord] {
  def meta = MyRecord
  object fail extends MongoCaseClassField[MyRecord, MyCaseClass](this)
}

object MyRecord extends MyRecord with MongoMetaRecord[MyRecord]
```

However this works fine if I use `String` instead of `Enumeration`. Is there any way to use enumerations in case class fields or should use a different type of field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite certain that this will only work with native types like String, Int, Float, Double, Boolean, etc, but not Enumerations. I am really certain that this is due to serialization.

Comment: You are right, after digging around without success I decided to use `BsonRecord` as a container instead of `MongoCaseClassField`.

Comment: Could you please mark it as "accepted", so it shows up as "answered" rather than unanswered? :) Thanks (I Like to keep it clean)

Comment: Not sure I follow you, the answer was accepted. Check your profile for Sep 14, you got +15 from me: http://stackoverflow.com/users/319315/franz-bettag?tab=reputation

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing mongoDB doesn't place nice with scala enums, I use a decorator method as a work around.

Say you have this enum:

```
object EmployeeType extends Enumeration {
  type EmployeeType = Value
  val Manager, Worker = Value
}
```

and this mongodb record:

```
import EmployeeType._
case class Employee(
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId
)
```

In your mongoDB, store the integer index of the enum instead of the enum itself:

```
case class Employee(
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  employeeTypeIndex: Integer = 0
){
  def employeeType = EmployeeType(employeeTypeIndex); /* getter */
  def employeeType_=(v : EmployeeType ) = { employeeTypeIndex= v.id} /* setter */
}
```

The extra methods implement getters and setters for the employee type enum.